# How to add save to phone google button and add pay passes via xamarin mobile app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-pay

I have created the Google pay Passes successfully with ASP.Net core backed and my rest api successfully return JWT Token. And alo i used the save to phone web button and used JWT that working fine but i need to integrate the passes with my Xamarin Forms Application, In xamrin how i add Save to phone button and how to bind the JWT along with that button?

Comment: can you share how you're able to generate the passes? 
I'm specifically getting hung up on the 'trusted users' and 'class review status'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have found  the solution. If your back end server return the JWT for your google pay pass you can achieve this in Xamarin forms via dependency service.

If you can use JWT link and intent, JWT POST request method and native Android SDK. Please refer this [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/implementing-the-api/save-to-google-pay#from-native-android-app)

My pass type is Loyality card so, I have used [JWT link and intent method](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/implementing-the-api/save-to-google-pay#use-jwt-link-and-intent)

Before integrate the pass with your App, you can test your JWT with chrome browser. Please hit this(https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/{jwt_generated}) url with your JWT in the chrome browser, if the JWT is fine, you will see the pass in the browser

To achieve

1. Create an interface in your PCL project

   ```
         namespace App.DependencyServices
         {
             public interface IGPayPass
             {
                void LoadGPayPass(string JWT);
             }
         }
   ```
2. Create native implementation in your Android project

   ```
   public class GPayImplementation : IGPayPass
   {
    /// <summary>
    ///     summary:
    ///         This methode load the google pay pass from the JWT and open the pay passes in Google pay app
    ///         To show the pass in google pay we have to create an ACTION_VIEW
    ///         If pass is the loyality pass we can use the JWT link and intent method(https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/implementing-the-api/save-to-google-pay#use-jwt-link-and-intent)
   ///         To load the pass send the https request to google pass class object like https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/{jwt_generated}
   ///
   ///     parameters:
   ///         JWT : The server return this token for pay passes and pass via dependency service to this native implementation
   ///
   ///     returns:
   ///
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="JWT"></param>
      public void LoadGPayPass(string JWT)
      {
         //create context
         Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

         string url = "https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/" + JWT;

         //Send the https request to google pay pass class object via Android intent
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url));

         //Assign new task Flag for intent otherwise runtime exepption will return
         intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
         context.StartActivity(intent);
      }
   }
   ```
3. Consume the native implementation in PCL project via dependency service

   ```
           if (response.HttpCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
           {
               ResponseSting = response.Results.ToString();

               //Remove quates from the JWT string
               MembershipCardAndroidJWT = ResponseSting.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');

               //Pass The JWT string via dependency service to the Anroid native Environment
               DependencyService.Get<IGPayPass>().LoadGPayPass(MembershipCardAndroidJWT);
           }
   ```

In the UI,  There is no any default button like google web button but you have to follow the brand guide lines (https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/api-guidelines/brand-guidelines)

you can use any kind of button and trigger this method via onclik or command

This method consuming the pass JWT from the server and pass to the google wallet

[image]

[image]